# I do have <meta property="fb:app_id" content="1000000000000000" />

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, plugins, comments

I am trying to set up the comments box on my site.
I have created an app for doing that.

On site I have the meta code for fb app id

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1000000000000000" />
```

inside the head tags.
And I have this piece of code for facebook:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=1000000000000000     ";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

At the right place of the page I have a div with fb-comments class. The comment plugin works BUT the comments are not shown at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments.

When I go to debug at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing
and insert there my page link I get some strange warnings saying among other things that

#### The 'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly provided, Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog.

But I have this meta tag with fb:app_id property!

What am I doing wrong?
Cheers.

Comment: can you add the relevant url?

Comment: the page with comment box is http://annchess.ru/kasparovs300bestgames.php

Comment: i only get warnings about og:url, og:image and og:title not existing

Comment: Now for some reason I stopped getting fb:app_id error. But the comments still don't show up at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments . I wish I knew why.